# how to get Longitude and Latitude useing NETWORK_PROVIDER?

Tags: android

when used GPS_PROVIDER the application work fine, but when used NETWORK_PROVIDER the application was stopped by force. Why? are my permissions not complete?? please help me by making my code working, thanx

```
 public class My_location extends Activity implements LocationListener {
EditText ET1,ET2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_location);

//  Log.i("onCreate_My_location", "begin");
    ET1=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    ET2=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    ET1.setText("1.0000");
    ET2.setText("1.0000");
```

LocationManager LM1=(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

LM1.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,1,this);

```
    //Log.i("onCreate_my_location", "End");
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location L1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Log.i("onLocationChanged",String.valueOf(L1.getLongitude()));
    //Log.i("onLocationChanged",String.valueOf(L1.getLatitude()));
    //Log.i("onLocationChanged",String.valueOf(L1.getAltitude()));
    ET1.setText("C.0000");
    ET2.setText("C.0000");
    ET1.setText(String.valueOf(L1.getLongitude()));
    ET2.setText(String.valueOf(L1.getLatitude()));

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
}
  }
```

Comment: i used 
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**instead of using specific provider use best provider, which will give you more accuracy in your location**

use code given below which will give you location by choosing best provider automatically :

```
LocationManager LM1=(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
String provider=LM1.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
LM1.requestLocationUpdates(provider,0,1,this);
```

**Edit:**

for Your Code you Can Check network State before `requestLocationUpdates`

i think this can avoid the crash :

```
if(LM1.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))
 {
  LM1.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,1,this);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you Tarsem for your help, why the application crash when using NETWORK_PROVIDER, is there problem in my code, please help me to get it run using NETWORK_PROVIDER. I think there is specific permission is missing.

Comment: @YousifAladdinAl-neamy see my updated answer to avoid the crash !

Comment: @YousifAladdinAl-neamy but i will suggest you to choose best provider before requesting !

Comment: thank you, your first code is better and very helpful, i thought there is permission missing, but when i use the app on my phone it work fine, sorry my bad i west your time.  can you give me code or link uses the different providers in best way with there permissions. thank you again for being helpful and listening.

Comment: @YousifAladdinAl-neamy to use network_provider you will have to test it on physical device, it will always crash on emulator ! i am testing a code which will provide us the location moving one step and provides  changed location's latitude and longitude with one step only ! tomorrow i will provide you the code if its succeeded :)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the network location provider is enabled or not.

```
try {
    network_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
} catch(Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

If the provider is enabled then only you can use that. Also, for location updates using a network provider, I think giving the minDistance value as 1 is meaningless as coarse location is anyway not very accurate. You might want to change that value to 50 or 100 meters.